# Recreate this Dry Acrylic brush from Corel Painter in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush, corel-painter

https://youtu.be/zC3OxonJcXQ?t=57

In this video, he uses the Acrylic - Dry Brush from Corel Painter. Is there a way to recreate these properties in photoshop?

He mentions using the paint brush at about the 1 minute mark, demonstrates its properties at abotu 1:15 - 2 minutes, and uses it for the rest of the video.

Comment: That's a 20 minute video.. are you expecting others to A) sit through the video ads, then B) either sit through the video until it reaches a section referencing an acrylic brush or scour a 20 minute video to try and figure out what *specific* brush you may referring to? -- In general.. Painter is fantastic at mimicking real life brushes.. Photoshop is not as adept at that.

Comment: Sorry, he uses the brush throughout the video, but demonstrates its properties at about 1:15 - 2 minutes.

Comment: @BillyKerr I added the timeStamp looks like it's not working. Don't know why.

Comment: @Vikas - yeah don't know what's up with that. Wasn't working, but now it is. Weird

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks quite similar to Photoshop's Mixer Brush functionality, although not identical.

In the example below I used a brush tip like this, which I borrowed from one of Kyle's Dry Media brushes, also brush spacing was set to around 3%. You can obviously use any brush tip you want.

[image]

Then used it with the Mixer Brush settings shown here, although you can play around with the settings as you please.

[image]

And here's an example of the Mixer Brush in action. Please ignore the brush cursor here as my screen recording software doesn't display its size or location properly.

[image]

It's also possible to Clean the brush, and use it to smoosh around the paint to allow blending etc.

[image]

[image]

You can also get a brush to run out of paint by using the Dry Light Loaded preset. Although I note with the Wetness set to Zero, the Mixer is greyed out.

[image]

It might be worth your while actually searching for Photoshop tutorials on painting with the Mixer Brush to be honest, rather than trying to compare it with other software like Corel Painter. I'm not an expert on digital painting by any stretch of the imagination. There may be more efficient ways to work with the tool.

Comment: what do you mean by 'clean the brush'?

Comment: @TKoL Sorry, it's one of the options on the tool controls. I've added it to the answer.

Comment: @TKoL I found a nice youtube tutorial which goes into far more detail on the Mixer Brush here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ovqr6q00UYM

Comment: thank you for this advice

Answer (score 0):

I've been attempting to do the same thing! The biggest problem that I've run into is the color blending happening. To put what's happening in Corel into Photoshop terms: It's a mixer brush with flow and mix jitter on fade but, the mix jitter is *reversed*. Meaning the beginning of the stroke there is 0% mixing and at the end of the stroke it's essentially just the smudge tool. Unfortunately, I've not found a method that lets you flip this.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/109054)